# Is there a major difference between an id and a tag? Which one will be more appropriate?

Tags: java, android, json

I am using a LayoutInflater to add dynamic views every time I press the button function. I am trying to add a tag/id to the view so that I can identify each element.

I have tried setTag as well as setId but always seem to end up not being able to find the element

```
public void onAddField(View v) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
    rowView.setTag(a);
    //rowView.setId(a);
    getdata2();
    parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
    Log.d(String.valueOf(parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(a).getId()), "onAddField: " + type2_workout_mySpinner.findViewWithTag(a).);
    getdata2();
    a = a +1;
}

private void getdata2() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest("http://.../getDataCategories.php",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {
                        j = new JSONObject(response);
                        result = j.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
                        catdetails(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}



private void catdetails(JSONArray j) {
    for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);
            arrayList2.add(json.getString(CategoryType_idArray));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    type2_workout_mySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arrayList2));
}
```

I would like to be able to use a getter class to get the values of each element that I have added for example the value of multiple spinner values selected

Comment: Semantically, an ID is pretty much what it says; a way to identify a given `View`. Tags are more like metadata, extra info that you want to attach to a `View`. That said, in either case, you need to call the corresponding `findView*()` method on some ancestor of the desired `View`. The only instance of either of those methods I see in your code is `findViewWithTag(a)`, which seems to be called on a `Spinner`, but your dynamically created `View`s aren't going to be in that. Have you tried calling either on `parentLinearLayout`?

Comment: @MikeM. thank you for your response. 

Something like parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(a).findViewWithTag(a)? 
If so how would I link this to the spinner(s)? 
Will this have to happen in a different method or will this be in the onAddField method?

Comment: You don't need the `getChildAt(a)` (though if the order and number of the rows is constant, you could just use that instead of either `findView*()` method). I don't really understand how the `Spinner` fits into all of this.

Comment: @MikeM. The view that I'm adding contains a spinner so basically what I'm trying to do is everytime I add a new view to my list I want to select a value from the spinner from that view and the screen will end up having a list of views with multiple spinners.

Comment: I want to then at a later stage use these values from each spinner to add into a database

Comment: If the `field` layout is more than just a `<Spinner>`, then its ID and `rowView`'s ID are different things, and you wouldn't be trying to find anything within the `Spinner`; i.e., you wouldn't be calling `type2_workout_mySpinner.findView*()` at all. You can get the `Spinner` in the current row right after you inflate it using `rowView.findViewById(R.id.your_spinner_id)`, and you can set the current `Adapter` on that. Later on, you can get a given row using `parentLinearLayout.findView*()`, and then call `findViewById(R.id.your_spinner_id)` on that row to get its individual `Spinner`.

Comment: thank you @MikeM. it worked!